# Javascript on click not working for setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have this following code -

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Rebound</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function ShowRandom() {
        var $span = $(".random");
        var oldTop = 0;
        var oldLeft = 0;
        var leftPos = 10;
        var topPos = 10;
        var flag = true;

        $(".random").on("click", "#lion", function(event) {
                alert(event.target.id);
            }); 

        $span.fadeOut(500, function() {

            var maxLeft = $(window).width() - $span.width();
            var maxTop = $(window).height() - $span.height();

            oldTop = topPos;
            oldLeft = leftPos;

            leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLeft + 1));
            topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxTop + 1));          

            $span.css({ left: leftPos, top: topPos }).fadeIn(500);
        });
    };
    ShowRandom();
    setInterval(function(){         
        $('.random').append("<span class='lab'></span>");
        ShowRandom(); 
    }, 1500);
     $('.random').delegate('.lab', 'click', function() {
        $('.random').remove('.lab');
        alert('single event trigger');
    });


</script>
<style>
    span { 
        display: inline-block; 
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <span class="random"><img src="lion.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" id="lion"></span>

    </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

I want only one alert box when I click on the image. But I get multiple alert boxes. Is there a way around it?

Thank You

Comment: You are appending an eventListener in the interval! (by callin ShowRandom() ). So every 1500ms it will add a listener..

Comment: Why not just set up the click handler once, instead of adding another one every time the function runs? Or use `.off()` before calling `.on()`

Comment: If I just create an onclick event handler for class="random" the function does not execute...

Comment: what is clicking the image supposed to do?

Comment: Print alert with name of the div...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try moving

```
$(".random").on("click", "#lion", function(event) {
     alert(event.target.id);
});
```

outside the ShowRandom function.

ex:

```
function ShowRandom(){...};

$(function(){

   $(".random").on("click", "#lion", function(event) {
         alert(event.target.id);
    }); 

    ShowRandom();

    setInterval(function(){
        $('.random').append("<span class='lab'></span>");
        ShowRandom(); 
    }, 1500);

    ...

});
```

Comment: @Fox it will. The `.on` registers the `click` event for every specified element (present or future) so you only need to run it once

Answer (score 4):

Because you keep hooking up the click event on every interval.

Every internal you add another event, it does not override the previous one.

Comment: Can you suggest me a solution. I tried adding a onclick event on the class "random" but it is not called.